# Multivariate normal distribution and sum of singular values

Tags: normal-distribution, svd

Using a multivariate normal distribution I've (numerically) computed the expectation value of $x^Tx$:

$$ 
<x^Tx> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^k|Z|)}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} x^Tx \exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^TZ^{-1}x) \mathrm{ d}^k x
$$

Now it turns out, if I divide this by the sum of the singular values of $Z$ then the answer is equal (up to floating point precision) to 1.

$$
\frac{<x^Tx>}{ \sum \sigma_i } = 1
$$

Anyone knows if this is always the case for multivariate normal distributions? Is there a proof?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, was simpler than I thought - since $Z$ is positive definite, then the sum of the singular values is equal to the trace of $Z$.

We know:
$$
Z = <x x^T>
$$
thus, the components of $Z$ are
$$
Z_{ij} = <x_i x_j>
$$
and
$$
\sum Z_{ii} = \sum <x_i^2>=  \left<\sum x_i^2\right> = <x^Tx>
$$

Comment: Hi, so is $Z$ the covariance matrix of $<x^T\ x>$ ?